# Intellisense doesn't recognise the motor class of pybricks, but everything else

Tags: python, intellisense, micropython, pybricks-micropython

I want to code with pybricks and so far, everything worked, except of the Motor class. I use Visual Studio Code.
This are the imports:

```
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import ColorSensor
from pybricks.ev3devices import Motor
from pybricks.parameters import Port
```

Everything but the Motor is marked green [Image of the imports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkibM.png), and I can't see all the methods for the motor. All other classes work fine. It seems to be an error with intellisense or it isn't imported correctly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Edit: I now got to try this problem on another computer and I got the same result. Maybe it's a problem with the package or Intellisense does, for some reason, not recognise the motor class?

Comment: What editor is this?  VSCode?  Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, Visual Studio Code. Sorry, forgot to mention it

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Which version of Pybricks and the VS Code Python extension are you using?

Comment: I installed pybricks via pip from the github page, I found the command on https://github.com/pybricks/support/issues/10. VS Code Python: v2021.11.1422169775

Answer (score 0):

Try using pybricks-stubs using `pip3 install pybricks-stubs`
https://pypi.org/project/pybricks-stubs/